# convert table to CSV ENGINE with null VALUES

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE orders ENGINE=CSV;
```

**ERROR 1178 (42000): The storage engine for the table doesn't support nullable columns**

In table I have nulls values.
 How convert to csv table  ?

When converting back to InnoDB ENGINE return NULL  values. HOW do it?

Comment: Either change the definition of the table and update the data so that there are no null values, or use `SELECT... INTO OUT FILE` to create a separate CSV file

Comment: This limitation is directly stated in manual ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/se-csv-limitations.html ) saying that null is not allowed and all columns have to be "not null".

Answer (score 1):

after generating the table, before altering it to use engine csv
you must use 'alter table' to change the relevant columns to 'not null'

i.e.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp1 AS ( SELECT created_ts from accounts ); \
update tmp1 set created_ts='' where created_ts is null; \
alter table tmp1 CHANGE COLUMN created_ts created_ts TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ; \
alter table tmp1 engine=CSV;
```